# I need to write a custom Gulp task that will remove attributes from my HTML

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I am needing a Gulp task that will go through all assigned HTML documents and remove certain attributes (such as style=""). I thought I may have been able to do it the same way I do it through the browser, but looks like not. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
// function to take multiple attributes from an element
const discardAttributes = (element, ...attributes) =>
  attributes.forEach((attribute) => element.removeAttribute(attribute));

// run the function on multiple elements
document.querySelectorAll("table, thead, tbody, tr, th, td").forEach((elem) => {
  discardAttributes(elem, "cellspacing", "cellpadding", "width", "style");
});
```

I would like to then take the above formula and create a gulp.task like so:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("clean",  async () => {
 gulp.src("src/*.html")
  .pipe(discardAttributes())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

If there is a plug-in I can use that will do this please share, but also, I'd like to learn how to do it manually like this.

Would I need to use through2?

Thank you.

Comment: gulp only runs in Node.js, while the function you wrote will only work in a browser.

Comment: Do you know of any node.js modules that will go through HTML documents and delete certain attributes? I tried htmlmini but it doesn't have that feature, neither does html-lint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some node dom library, and wrap it with gulp. For example you could try jsdom and wrapper gulp-dom:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const dom = require("gulp-dom");

gulp.task("default", async () => {
 gulp.src("src/*.html")
  .pipe(dom(function() {

      // function to take multiple attributes from an element
      const discardAttributes = (element, ...attributes) =>
        attributes.forEach((attribute) => element.removeAttribute(attribute));

      // run the function on multiple elements
      return this.querySelectorAll("table, thead, tbody, tr, th, td").forEach((elem) => {
       discardAttributes(elem, "cellspacing", "cellpadding", "width", "style");
    });

  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Comment: This looks promising, I am about to try it. Questions: I don't see jsdom anywhere in the code, how does it come into play here? Excuse my dumb question but I am new to node.

UPDATE: According to npm docs, "[Gulp-dom] plugin wraps jsdom. Though, this plugin does not enable all features provided by jsdom. The sole purpose for jsdom in this plugin is to parse a HTML document into a DOM so we can run operations on it."

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Here is what I did. (1) I installed jsdom as a devDependancy (2) I installed gulp-dom as a devDependancy (3) I pasted the code above and ran gulp. Sorry I can't upvote yet.

Comment: The gulp-dom plugin includes the jsdom, no need to install it separately. If you are happy with the answer you can accept it.